# Calculate the probability of co-occuring keywords in my text file

Tags: python, list, nltk

I have two text files, the first contains one sentence each line and the second contains one keyword each line like this :

```
Firstword
Secondword
Thirdword
...
```

I want to use PMI to calculate how much more- or less likely some keywords are to co-occur in my text file.

Here's what I did :

```
from nltk.collocations import BigramCollocationFinder, BigramAssocMeasures
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string
from collections import Counter
import re

with open("./keywords.txt", encoding='utf8') as thebook:
    keywords = set(word.lower().strip(string.punctuation) for word in thebook.read().split())
words = re.findall(r'\w+', open('sentence_file.txt').read().lower())
if words in keywords : 
    finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(words)
    bgm = BigramAssocMeasures()
    score = bgm.pmi
    collocations = {'_'.join(bigram): pmi for bigram, pmi in finder.score_ngrams(score)}

collocations
```

This gives me the following error:

```
---> 12 if words in keywords :
     13     finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(words)
     14     bgm = BigramAssocMeasures()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list''
```

Note that program worked fine when I tested it on one sentence and the pmi between its own words. I have more trouble adding the two files. Any help?

Comment: If you are trying to check if any word in `words` is in `keywords` you can convert `words` to a set and check the intersection of the two: `if set(words) & keywords:` https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

Comment: words is a list. You have to use string in the list. You can use words[0] or iterate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `words` is a `list` of strings from the regex matches. `Keywords`, meanwhile, is a `set`. In Python, you can't make a `set` from a list of lists, because `lists` are unhashable. So when you try to look-up your `list` in a `set`, you get the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

In your case, you can either iterate through `words` and check their presence in `keywords`. Or vice versa, depending on the size of the list and the end goal:

```
for word in words:
    if word in keywords:
        # do something
        break # potentially break your loop if you only need to find one match
```

or

```
for kword in keywords:
    if kword in words:
        # do something
        break # potentially break your loop if you only need to find one match
```

Or, you could check the intersection of the `words` and `keywords`, as one of the commenters suggested.